# DeleteFiles task exclude single file from match list

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to setup the DeleteFiles task to delete all DLL files that start with 'ab' except for a specific one.

For example if I have:

```
abfile.one.dll
abfile.two.dll
abotherfile.dll
System.Stuff.dll (there are 20-30 of these that need to be included)
abdontdeleteme.dll
```

I expect the resulting files:

```
System.Stuff.dll
abdontdeleteme.dll
```

I've tried a bunch of different configs but none have worked. The config that I thought made the most sense was:

```
  - task: DeleteFiles@1
    displayName: 'Cleanup Assemblies'
    inputs:
      sourceFolder: ${{parameters.theDirectoryToCleanup}}
      contents: ab*.dll !abdontdeleteme.dll
```

This config does nothing. Setting `System.Debug` to `true` and looking at the output I see:

```
##[debug]pattern: 'D:/a/1/b/api/bin/ab*.dll !abdontdeleteme.dll'
##[debug]applying include pattern against original list
##[debug]0 matches
##[debug]0 final results
```

I also tried with just `ab*.dll` which worked but that deletes the one DLL I care about. Is there a way to exclude a specific file from the match list?

**Edit**

As per a suggestion in the comments I tried the following to the same results (no files were deleted):

```
- task: DeleteFiles@1
    displayName: 'Cleanup Assemblies'
    inputs:
      sourceFolder: ${{parameters.theDirectoryToCleanup}}
      contents:
        ab*.dll 
        !abdontdeleteme.dll
```

**Edit 2**

I tried the following:

```
- task: DeleteFiles@1
    displayName: 'Cleanup Assemblies'
    inputs:
      sourceFolder: ${{parameters.theDirectoryToCleanup}}
      contents: |
        ab*.dll 
        !(abdontdeleteme.dll)
```

This deletes everything except 'abdontdeleteme.dl'

```
- task: DeleteFiles@1
    displayName: 'Cleanup Assemblies'
    inputs:
      sourceFolder: ${{parameters.theDirectoryToCleanup}}
      contents:
        ab*.dll 
        !(abdontdeleteme.dll)
```

This again matches to nothing and nothing gets deleted.

Comment: I believe each thing in the "contents" section needs to be on it's own line

Comment: @BrianM, thanks for the suggestion. I tried it and had the same results :/

Comment: One more suggestion....  along with putting them on separate lines, put () around the file you want ignored, so you'd have !(abdontdeleteme.dll)

Comment: Also, per the example on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/delete-files?view=azure-devops, you have to put a | after contents: if you move the first file down to the next line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a lot of frustration I gave up and used Powershell because it can do what I want. It's not the best solution but it works as some of the other steps require a Windows image anyways. The code that worked is:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: "Cleanup Web Services"
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: Remove-Item "path\to\my\stuff\*" -Include "ab*.dll" -Exclude "abdontdeleteme.dll"
```

Comment: I found myself in the same spot.  Frustrated by the pattern matching not working for the DeleteFiles task.  Also, the powershell has the benefit that you can try it out on the command line to get the parameters just right before putting it in the YAML script.  Thanks for sharing this.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the tasks compile logic, you's better convert your syntax direction, to tell the system what files you need to keep.

So, just try `!(System.Stuff.dll|abdontdeleteme.dll)` in task definition:

```
- task: DeleteFiles@1

  displayName: 'Delete files'

  inputs:

    SourceFolder: ${{parameters.theDirectoryToCleanup}}

    Contents: !(System.Stuff.dll|abdontdeleteme.dll)
```

---

From the build log, you could easily found that when you specify multiple matching expressions in different line:

```
    ab*.dll 
    !(abdontdeleteme.dll)
```

All of them are compiled them separately into `source path/ab*.dll`, `source path/!(abdontdeleteme.dll)`. But currently, tasks cannot solve them both at the same time.

Meanwhile, if you specify those 2 expression into one line, the system identified them as `source path/ab*.dll !abdontdeleteme.dll`. Obviously, delete files could not be succeed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is there any way of achieving this without specifically name the DLLs I don't want to delete? I should have mentioned in the question that there are probably 20-30 assemblies that need to be kept, I only listed one to keep the example short

Comment: @amura.cxg, of course. You can specify the name as wildcard here. But this needs you find out the regular of those dlls(you don't want it delete) name.